# Roll the dice until get the same point in two successive rolls

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this assignment about dice game, which require to write a program that roll the dice until it get the same score on two successive rolls and show the result of the rolls. Could you please show me what is the problem in this code. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Roll the dice</title>
<script>
function hwc() {
  var roll, score, scorep, output = "";
  score = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
  output = "<table><tr><th>Try time</th><th>Score</th></tr>";
  scorep = score;

  for (roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll = roll + 1) {
    output = output + "<tr><td>" + roll + "</td>";
    score = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    output = output + "<td>" + score + "</td>";
    output = output + "</tr>";

    if (scorep == score) break;

    scorep = score;
  }
  output = output + "</table>";
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = output;
  output = output + "You have rolled the same score on two successive rolls, whose point are " + scorep;
  document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = output;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button3 onclick="hwc()">Part 3 - Roll until the dice get the same score on two consecutive rolls.</button3>
</div>
<p id="id1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this program, in some cases, it just shows 1 roll. However, according to the requirement above, you have to roll at least two times. Could you please show me what is the problem in this code. Thank you!

Comment: Note the first assignment before the for statement would actually be the first roll, so the times you think there was only one roll there were actually two

Comment: So is there any way to show all the rolls?

Comment: Yea write the first roll into the table like you do in the for loop or simply get rid of the initial assignment  so all the rolls start in the for loop

Comment: Everything is all right now. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're limiting yourself to 999 rolls - while the probability is very low, it's still probable that you can roll 999 rolls without a double

Comment: Can I fix the condition from "roll < 1000" to "roll > 0"?

Comment: just use a `while(true)` loop instead, or you could `for (roll = 1; true; roll = roll + 1)` I guess